# Customize Video Controls for "Video" tag

Tags: javascript, html, css, video

Hey :) I have [this](http://codepen.io/luisgallego/pen/fyumv) video and I want the controls to be outside the player; something like this:

[Click to see Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XSVFo.jpg)

Is there a cross-browser way to do this? Even if I have to create custom controls (What would be perfectly fine)?

This is my first question here, so sorry if I'm not being specific enough.

Comment: To those who put this topic on hold; I don't see *any* questions asked about what further information could be provided. He's even volunteered to offer more information in whatever way necessary. Furthermore, two people have been able to provide at least halfway-satisfactory answers below. Please do not put questions on hold without giving some thought to the reason for closing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a premade video player script such as this one: http://www.videojs.com/ - many customization options are available.

Comment: And... Using that one, am I able to get the current video position? Thanks

Comment: Not sure what you mean by get current video position. But the api is very extensive, see the full api documentation: https://github.com/videojs/video.js/blob/stable/docs/api/vjs.Player.md

Answer (score 0):

Usually, the most straightforward way you would do this is by removing the `controls` attribute of the video tag, and then writing the controls as separate HTML elements, which are hooked up via JavaScript to play/pause/navigate the video. This will mean the video box area will have no controls of its own, so users will be dependent on the outside controls. (However, note that given correct CSS styling, they don't *have* to be located outside)

Comment: If I'm using custom controls, How can I make the navigation bar? Thanks